# Time intervals calculations across record groups

Tags: sql, teradata, datediff, gaps-and-islands

We have machines running and creating run logs of start and stop times that bleed into consecutive reports. Each run consists of 10 timestamps (5 starts and 5 stops). Trouble is, the (n-1)th run ends in a start date (Ex. row 11 of Run_2), and the stop date I need is part of the nth run (row 10 of Run_3). I need to split start and stop times into separate columns.

The source table is structured this way.

```
Name ROW RUN    DATE_TS (this is a timestamp sorted desc)

A    1  Run_3   START1  
A    2  Run_3   STOP1  
A    3  Run_3   START2
A    4  Run_3   STOP2
A    5  Run_3   START3
A    6  Run_3   STOP3
A    7  Run_3   START4
A    8  Run_3   STOP4
A    9  Run_3   START5
A    10 Run_3   STOP5
A    11 Run_2   START1
A    12 Run_2   STOP1
A    13 Run_2   START2
A    14 Run_2   STOP2
A    15 Run_2   START3
A    16 Run_2   STOP3
A    17 Run_2   START4
A    18 Run_2   STOP4
A    19 Run_2   START5
A    20 Run_2   STOP5
A    21 Run_1   START1
A    22 Run_1   STOP1
A    23 Run_1   START2
A    24 Run_1   STOP2
A    25 Run_1   START3
A    26 Run_1   STOP3
A    27 Run_1   START4
A    28 Run_1   STOP4
A    29 Run_1   START5
A    30 Run_1   STOP5
```

Target (The start and stop indicate the rowid corresponding to the date from the source table)

```
Name    Start   Stop (replace row_id's with Actual timestamps)
A          3    2
           5    4
           7    6
           9    8
           11   10
           13   12
           15   14
           17   16
           19   18
           21   20
           23   22
           25   24
           27   26
           29   28
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you identify those runs, start & stop? Actual data would help.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original question.

Use can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select name, row as start,
             lag(row) over (partition by name order by row) as stop
      from t
     ) t
where name like 'START%';
```

Like the data in your question, this assumes that the data is perfectly interleaved -- so this is the simplest (or among the simplest) solutions.  If your data is actually more complex, then I would suggest that you ask another question with better sample data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. A couple of clarifications - The source date_ts is a column containing timestamp values. I entered text to highlight the calculation. Also, the target columns Start and Stop are the timestamp values corresponding to the row_id entered. I was trying to be as clear as possible. Given this, how would your SQL change?

Comment: @user1760691 . . . It would have been better to ask a new question rather than invalidating this answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get that. How would I state the question any differently? I don't post very often here.

Comment: @user1760691 . . . I answered the question you originally asked.  You realized that you had a different question.  This is a common occurrence.  When a question has one or more answers, it is usually better to just ask a new question.  The purpose of asking a question is not to start a dialog on "what is my real question".  It is to answer the question actually asked.